# Python Pandas lambda function to change all the values of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
AIRCRAFT
B738 (C-GKWJ)
A321 (C-FJNX)
```

and using this code to extract only TYPE,

```
def extract_type(aircraft):
    return aircraft.split(" ")[0]

data['TYPE'] = data['AIRCRAFT'].apply(lambda x: extract_type(x))
```

my expectation is:

```
AIRCRAFT       TYPE
B738 (C-GKWJ)  B738
A321 (C-FJNX)  A321
```

but im getting:

```
AIRCRAFT       TYPE
B738 (C-GKWJ)  B738 (C-GKWJ)
A321 (C-FJNX)  A321 (C-FJNX)
```

when testing extract_type function, it works fine

```
 def extract_type(aircraft):
     return aircraft.split(" ")[0]

    extract_type("B737 (C-GWJT)")
```

returns 'B737'

Why it doesn't work with data frame and lambda function? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use str.split

```
data['TYPE'] = data['AIRCRAFT'].str.split().str[0]
```

You get

```
    AIRCRAFT    TYPE
0   B738 (C-GKWJ)   B738
1   A321 (C-FJNX)   A321
```

You can also use str.extract though split is ideal

```
 data['TYPE'] = data['AIRCRAFT'].str.extract('(\w+)\s\(', expand = False)
```

Comment: Glad that it worked. You can accept the answer if the issue is completely resolved